# C++ Compiler only? (Netbeans)

Tags: c, netbeans, compiler-construction

I use Netbeans as my IDE. Now, I only need a compiler (i.e. not a full-featured development kit, as I already have one. Except it doesn't come with a C compiler) to compile C programs I write. However, I cannot find one that is only a simple compiler, I only stumble across full-blown 500MB compilers, while I just need a few MB compiler that supports advanced features such as templates, RTTI, Qualifiers etc.

Comment: so do you need a C compiler or a C++ compiler? your title and question are not clear

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: C++, I thought C referred to the family? (i.e. not only a particular version like C# ). I want C++ compilers, but supports for languages like C Sharp also would be an advantage.

Comment: Also, C does not have templates or RTTI. These are in C++ (a different language than C). [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is a *collection* of compilers, including `gcc` (mostly for C code) and `g++`  (mostly for C++ code). And C# is not C or C++ compatible (but C++ is nearly C compatible).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. Windows 8 x86.

Comment: I am having a very satisfactory experience with CodeBlocks + GCC(MinGW). It works well in Windows as much as in Ubuntu. I am using in both systems.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't checked the file size, but I recommend [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).  If you are on Windows, I would recommend the GCC port called [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: Would you mind pointing to any article or anything as to how to set `MinGW` so that the compiler gets set in Netbeans.I'm myself struck with this!

Comment: Yes, that's the one I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW is the best solution. I use it too. but if you feel it's too much work. Try using [dev-C++](http://bloodshed-dev-c.en.softonic.com/download#downloading/). it's a simple light weight compiler.